# Custom font displays very bigger size in different simulator sizes (e.g iPhone 5c, 6s, etc)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, custom-font

I am working on iOS app, I added some custom font to my app. After applying that font, its working fine in iPhone 7 Plus, but if I run that app in iPhone SE or 6S, 6 Pus, showing very big font sizes compare with 7 Plus. Due to this, my view getting very worst layouts. Even app icons also showing big on above-mentioned devices simulators. Really strange, I am checking with Simulator as I don't have the device now.

By the way, we are not using constraints, we are using auto resizing.

Xcode version : Xcode 8,
Simulator iOS 10.2

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues when I was not using auto resizing properly, try to figure out the auto resizing once again and see the result for different devices on storyboard itself.